# jQuery CSS3 Transforms not Working to Rotate a DiV

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to rotate a soan class called `.arrow` on mouseenter event to 90 degree. This is easily possible with CSS3 transformation as:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

I tried to use same code in jquery but it is not working! Can you please let me what is wrong with my code?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".list").on("mouseenter", function() {
      $( '.arrow' ).css({'background-position':'0px 0px',
                         '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
                         '-moz-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
                         '-o-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
                         '-ms-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
                         'transform': 'rotate(90deg)'
      });
    });
 });
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/wqQ8p/) Link

and code is like

```
<div class="list"></div>
<p>
<div class="arrow"></div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".list").on("mouseenter", function() {
       $( '.arrow' ).css({'background-position':'0px 0px',
                          ' -webkit-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
                           '-moz-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
                           '-o-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
                           '-ms-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
                            'transform': 'rotate(90deg)'
                         });

   }).on("mouseleave", function() {
     $( '.arrow' ).css({'  -webkit-transform': 'rotate(-90deg)',
                           '-moz-transform': 'rotate(-90deg)',
                           '-o-transform': 'rotate(-90deg)',
                           '-ms-transform':'rotate(-90deg)',
                           'transform': 'rotate(-90deg)'
    });
}); 
});
```

**IMPORTANT** the code rotate without using the second part of the code. I mean the `.on("mouseleave"` part if you delete that part first part of code rotates the box!

Comment: If you inspect the `.arrow` element(s) do you see any updated HTML? Otherwise are you getting an error in your JS console? Also, you can use `addClass()` to add a class to the element instead, and then you setup CSS for the class that has your rotation transform.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Hi I updated the code and add a new jsfiddle link above, thanks

Comment: If you put in "0" on mouseleave css, it sets itself back to starting position. (tested firefox) Is that what you want? 
http://jsfiddle.net/wqQ8p/1/

Comment: Just to add here. i believe you will have issues in older browsers with the rotate functionality. That is why I have implemented a plugin for this feature: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: Hi Daniel, I test your jsfiddle on chrome but it is nit working! well what I want is just rotating the blue div on mouse over and back to previous position on mouse out

Comment: That plugin works on chrome! I gotta run, so I will have a look later.

Comment: You have spaces in your webkit version, so it fails in Chrome. Maybe that's the only problem.

Comment: Tested @Dave's comment and that solves the issue in Chrome. Theer are multiple solutions given, like .addClass(), pure CSS (best), or the way you do. The problem is the backward compatibility. They fail for Browsers < IE9. If you need that, then I suggest you use the plugin I advised.

Answer (score 1):

### Pure CSS solution

You don't need to use a script for that, use CSS hover pseudo selector instead.

Check out this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/wqQ8p/2/)

much simpler, cleaner, and easier to understand.

**HTML:** (nothing new here)

```
<div class="list"></div>
<p>
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.list
{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;  
    background-color:red;
}

.arrow{
    width:250px;
    height:350px; 
    background-color:blue;
}

.list:hover ~ .arrow
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

### Script

If you have to use a Script, use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
the hover function takes two arguments,

first argument: function for mouse in

second argument: function for mouse out.
again, this will be cleaner and easier to understand.

and finally: why is your code not working?
because the rotation is applied on the initial position of the element,
so `rotate(90)` and `rotate(-90)` are pretty much the same (at least for for rectangles).
if you want it to go back to normal when the mouse leaves, you'll have to apply `rotate(0)`
Check out this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/wqQ8p/5/) (this is your old code, I really recommend you to use the CSS way, or [that](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/wqQ8p/6/) way)

also: notice the whitespace you had before `webkit`.